# Is there an equivalent for C# Enumerable for converting string to byte array in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js

I'm Sending Hex string to a function and return it as Byte array using c# , but now the requirement is to do this in NodeJs .

i searched too much about this but non solutions gave me the same result

here is my c# code with this hex string

```
    `8001000501335688003300020002000200`

    public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        var byteArray = Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                         .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                         .Select(x =>Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x,2),16))
                         .ToArray();
        return byteArray;
    }
```

i tried this code in NodeJs but i didn't get the same result

```
    function StringToByteArray(hex) {
        var rangebytes = range(0, hex.length).filter(x => x % 2 == 0)
        var filteredHex = rangebytes.match(x => 
            Buffer.from(hex.substring(x, 2), "utf8"));

        return filteredHex;
     }

    function range(start, count) {
        return Array.apply(0, Array(count))
        .map(function (element, index) {
                        return index + start;
                });
      }
```

And here is the result from c# code 
 http://prntscr.com/m7xnzg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will convert a hex string to a byte array in Node.js:

```js
function hexStringToByteArray(hexStr) {
    let a = [];
    for(let c = 0; c < hexStr.length; c += 2) {
        a.push(parseInt(hexStr.substr(c, 2), 16));
    }
    return a;
}

console.log("Result: ", hexStringToByteArray("8001000501335688003300020002000200"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much this exactly answered my question , wish i can vote you up

Answer (score 1):

It is good to use [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) API for this:

```
Buffer.from('8001000501335688003300020002000200', 'hex')

// <Buffer 80 01 00 05 01 33 56 88 00 33 00 02 00 02 00 02 00>
```